# HTML5 and javascript playing video for a specific interval

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to play a video for a specific interval with HTML5 and javascript using setTimeout method, I cant get it to work..help please

```
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video01");

function playGreen()
{
    myVideo.currentTime=3;
    myVideo.play;
    setTimeout(myVideo.pause(),2000);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
setTimeout(myVideo.pause(),2000)
```

to

```
setTimeout(function(){
    myVideo.pause();
},2000);
```

In your version you were immediately calling `pause` and passing it's value to `setTimeout`, whereas the edited code supplies `setTimeout` with a new function that will call `pause` after 2 seconds.

Comment: Are you sure that your `playGreen` function is even getting called? Are you getting any error messages in your console? It sounds like the problem is caused elsewhere, can you show more code in your question?

Comment: i have found my problem - i dint add '()' after myVideo.play